# Cutting AVI videos in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video-editing

Is there a tool for Mac OS X which supports cutting .AVI files, but doesn't re-compress them? Command-line tools are also welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Then cut the video starting from the position specified with `-ss` for a duration specified with `-t`. `copy` ensures that video and audio are not re-encoded.

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy -ss 00:01:30 -t 0:0:20 output.avi
```

Comment: The codec options belong after the input option, otherwise they mean, "treat this input as `copy`". FFmpeg more or less uses a pipeline syntax here.

Comment: Thanks @slhck. `ffmpeg -i video.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:40:35 -t 0:3:00 out.avi` works great!

Comment: After a video is cut, the player (mplayer) can no longer jump to specific a time position. How to fix?