# ffmpeg trimmed video does not support jumping to a time position

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, video-editing, avi

After [a video is cut](https://superuser.com/questions/422698/cutting-avi-videos-in-mac-os-x), the player (mplayer) cannot jump to a specific time position anymore. Clicking the timeline will usually end the playback. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The trimmed video probably has a broken AVI index. The `idx1`  tag in the AVI file format identifies where the data chunks are, so if the index is missing, the player won't know where to look for data chunks at a given timestamp.

This is somewhat expected since the raw bitstream is cut off somewhere using FFmpeg's `-c:v copy` option in your linked question.

I'm not aware of any FFmpeg command to fix the index, but `mencoder` [should have it](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.txt).

> `-forceidx`
>
> Force index rebuilding.  Useful for files with broken index (A/V desync,  etc).   This will enable seeking in files where seeking was not possible.

If you download [this unofficial mencoder build](http://media.stefpause.co.uk/mplayer_osx/mencoder.zip) from [Stef Pause's blog](http://stefpause.com/apple/mac/mplayer-os-x-10rc1-and-mencoder-binaries/), you can try to fix the AVI.

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip mencoder.zip
chmod +x mencoder
mv mencoder /usr/local/bin/
```

Then, enter:

```
mencoder -forceidx input.avi -o output.avi -oac copy -ovc copy
```

This will recreate the index for your AVI file. Good luck — if it's not working, you're probably better of re-encoding the original video after trimming.

Comment: `-forceidx` output a smaller .avi (146 becomes 119MB) and corrupted the avi. I might need to go for the recode way...

Comment: AVI is a pesky container. If you re-encode, check out existing answers and [this](http://superuser.com/a/373024/48078) as well as [this](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/).